# Warning on setOnTouchListener() of all Views

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-nestedscrollview

Recently after updating Android Studio to 3.0 and everything was working fine, but from today it shows warning on every `setOnTouchListener()` of any view also the logic inside it dose not seem to work properly anymore, i don't exactly remember if i have updated any library.

Warning message:

```
Custom View 'NestedScrollView' has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick
```

[image]

After searching on Stackoverflow i implemented following solution but it did not remove the warning.

```
switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        //some code....
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        view.performClick();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: share your whole code

Comment: did you add `@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    // do what you want
    return true;
}` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe where to add performClick() method?

Comment: Any specific reason for downvoting ?

Answer (score 2):

Too late with an answer, but for others who is running into the same issue. Actually, the solution is given in the warning text: you need to override performClick() method in your class. Just put this code in it:

```
@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    return super.performClick();
}
```